# When a user visits my site without adding https://www. it removes all additional pathing/routes

Tags: express, https, dns

Essentially, my site revolves around sharing a generated link to share your content, and the share link looks like: `www.mywebsite.com/share/{uniqueLink}`

This works when a user explicitly visits: `https://www.mywebsite.com/share/{uniqueLink}` but if they do not include `https` or `www` eg: `mywebsite.com/share/{uniqueLink}` it simply redirects them to `https://www.mywebsite.com/` and I lose the path.

I'm not sure if this is something I need to configure in DNS or on my server side routing. I'm using a typical node-express serve and I know very little about networking/dns.

I hate to ask a question without being able to provide what Ive already tried, but I dont know where to begin, and I cannot find examples of this online.

Any help, even just a point in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: I know I provided a comment, but FYI, I also flagged this for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

When users do not use a literal URL, the browser is going to try to sort out what they typed. The behavior varies by browser (and possibly by the preferences the user selected).

A long time ago, these features were called "auto-complete" or "URL Fixup" in early-Firefox era in Mozilla browsers.

There's no substitute for a user clicking on a proper URL (and for your content to properly provide them that URL). Some browsers will send this to a search engine (or possibly a cloud-based URL translator). In my experience, the browser vendors rarely explain themselves (although if you look for early Firefox era, it's pretty clearly spelled out. I know that, because I was the contributor for that documentation.)

The basic reason: most of these forms of URL guessing sound good, but experience shows that most end up with terrible side effects.

Here's an example: early Netscape Navigator would assume a hostname that started with "ftp" was an FTP site. So "ftp.example.com" -> "ftp://example.com/".

As the internet matured, ftp server were replaced by websites focused on downloads. In many cases, admins keep the sites in DNS, intending for people to use "http://ftp.example.com/"

Opps.

---

So basically, you need to work thru each problem report by hand, to understand the failure (even as a clear problem description), but in the end, you can't control users that much, keep your URLs in docs and the web pages themselves explicit, that's what is in your control.